# WPF Video capture card preview

Tags: c#, wpf, video-capture, preview

I want to show the video input preview of a capture card in a WPF application.

I know it is easy to do so with a video file or stream using a MediaElement

```
<MediaElement x:Name="video" Source="test.mpg" Stretch="Fill"></MediaElement>
```

But how could i implement something similar with a Source being a video capture card, a webcam or any video input device?

I found [this CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control) article, but seems to be a lot of work and code (including an external library such as the Microsoft Expression Encoder), comparing with the line of code above.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no single line solution for your task. You can use _DirectShow_ (.NET wrapper available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet)) or _Media Foundation_ (.NET wrapper available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnet)). In both cases, there is a lot of work to do though.